# xsltProcessor setParameter : send an undefined number of params

Tags: php, xslt, parameters

I have an XSL file.

I have a PHP file with a XSLTProcessor named `$bob`.

I want to send to my xsl transformation some parameters.

So, I write this in my PHP file; for example :

```
$bob->setParameter('', 'message', 'hi');
```

In my XSL file, to get the parameter, I write this for example :

```
<xsl:param name="message" />
```

And if i want to display this param in my XSL, I do this :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$message" />
```

Here comes the problem.

I have to send to my XSL an undefined number of parameters, and I don't know how to do it. I tried several solutions but they were not relevant. I want to send for example 3 messages to my XSL, and I want my XSL to use them to produce a code like this :

```
<messages>
    <message>Hi</message>
    <message>it's bob</message>
    <message>How are you ?</message>
</messages>
```

Do you have a solution for me ?
It will be very nice.
Sorry if my english has mistakes.
Thanks you and have a good day.

**As asked, here is what I have and what I want to have** :

**(the following is separated)**

Here is a simplified version of my original XML, named posts.xml :

```
<posts>
    <post id="post1" >
        <titre>Hey</titre>
        <motscles>
            <motcle>Batman</motcle>
            <motcle>Cats</motcle>
        </motscles>
    </posts>
</posts>
```

Here is the XML i want to have in final :

```
<posts>
    <post id="post1" >
        <titre>Hey</titre>
        <motscles>
            <motcle>Batman</motcle>
            <motcle>Cats</motcle>
        </motscles>
    </posts>
    <post id="post2" >
        <titre>Toto</titre>
        <motscles>
            <motcle>Superman</motcle>
            <motcle>Dogs</motcle>
            <motcle>Cake</motcle>
        </motscles>
    </posts>
</posts>
```

I obtained the information of the post (titre, motscles) by an HTML form.
So my php file get the information, and send it to my XSL file :

```
// initialize xml and xsl
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('posts.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load('addpost.xsl');

// Initialize the XSLTProcessor
$addPost  = new XSLTProcessor();
$addPost->importStylesheet($xsl);

// Define parameters
$addPost->setParameter('', 'titre', $_POST['titre']);

// Get the modified xml
$xml = $addPost->transformToDoc($xml);

// Save the modified xml
$xml->save('posts.xml');
```

Here is a simplified version of my XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output 
        method="xml"
        indent="yes" 
        encoding="UTF-8"
        />

    <xsl:param name="titre" />
    <xsl:param name="motscles" />

    <xsl:template match="posts" >
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="post" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template de post -->
    <xsl:template name="post" >
        <post id="{$id}" >
            <titre><xsl:value-of select="$titre" /></titre>
            <motscles>
            </motscles>
        </post>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copier les nodes et attributs récursivement -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your original XML you transform? What is your XSL XML? You have only fractions of it which explains your issue well, however, as `setParameter` only allows to set one value per a name, it's not clear what you're trying to do. The original XML and the XSL would shed some more light.

Comment: user1786510: You might be interested in a more flexible and scalable solution than using a pipe-delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well decide on a separator character for your messages (i.e. a character that is ensured not to occur in a message), then pass in a string with the messages separated by that character e.g. if you choose `|` you pass in `$bob->setParameter('', 'message', "Hi|It's Bob|How are you?");`, then in your XSLT code to be used with libxslt use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"  
  exclude-result-prefixes="str">

<xsl:param name="message"/>

<xsl:variable name="msgs-rtf">
  <messages>
    <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($message, '|')">
       <message>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </message>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </messages>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$msgs-rtf"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As far as I know that extension function `str:tokenize` is supported in libxslt which PHP 5 uses for XSLT so you should be able to use it. Or you need to write a template that does the tokenization in XSLT itself

Comment: Thanks you too ! I try this immediately :)

Answer (score 2):

**I would just have *one* parameter, that is an XML document**. I would create this XML document before I invoke the transformation.

**This has some definit benefits compared to sending a single, pipe-delimited string**:

1. Every parameter is in its own element and this can be matched by a separate template in XSLT.
2. No recursive processing of a pipe-delimited string and no extension functions are needed.
3. More extensible and scalable.

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than using pipe-delimited strings, especially as XSLT 1.0 does not support a tokenize() function.

Comment: In theory I agree that passing in an XML document is better but according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php#74864 PHP respectively libxslt does not support a parameter that is a DOMDocument or node. And libxslt used by PHP supports the EXSLT tokenize so I think my answer is a practical option for a question tagged as PHP and XSLT. It doesn't help to suggest something as more scalable and extensible and cleaner if it does not work at all with the XSLT processor used by the poster of the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenation in PHP?

```
$bob->setParameter("", "message", "Hi:it's bob:How are you ?");
```

and tokenization in XSLT code:

```
<messages>
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($message,':')">
<message>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</message>
</xsl:for-each>
</messages>
```