# parsing in PHP variable to XSLT using setParameter

Tags: php, xml, xslt

i have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

i have this php code

```
<?php
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("test.xsl");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("test.xml");

$xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltProcessor->registerPHPFunctions();
$xsltProcessor->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
$xsltProcessor->setParameter('','s_name', 'title');
$xsltProcessor->setParameter('','s_value', 35);

echo $xsltProcessor->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
?>
```

and this is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"  exclude-result-prefixes="str">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>O/p</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book[price>$s_value]/$s_name">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here I want to send to my xsl transformation some parameters. which is `s_name` and `s_value`

this is giving me error

if i use only `s_value` then it works fine n xsl will be

```
<xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book[price>$s_value]/title">
```

if i use both then its not working

Comment: You can not put variables inside the path. Put a path into a whole variable I think works.

Comment: @hakre if i use `$s_value` then its working...

Comment: Yes, because it's a valid xpath variable, the other isn't because placed inside the path. You could try to compare the localname if that helps.

Comment: i have already tried that to put whole path in one variable but it still doesnt work

Comment: Then this does not work. Do the localname suggestion, compare that the elements name works. see [`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name)

Comment: even i have also try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218885/xsltprocessor-setparameter-send-an-undefined-number-of-params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218885/xsltprocessor-setparameter-send-an-undefined-number-of-params) this is giving me totally different output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid XPath:

```
/bookstore/book[price>$s_value]/$s_name
```

because a variable cannot occur after a slash like that.  In order to accomplish what you are looking to do, try this:

```
/bookstore/book[price>$s_value]/*[local-name() = $s_name]
```

Comment: i got the output but there is warning like Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: compilation error: file file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/menu_xml/test3/test.xsl line 1 element stylesheet in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\menu_xml\test3\index.php on line 10 and Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\menu_xml\test3\index.php on line 10

Comment: Are you using a `version=` other than `1.0` in your stylesheet?  Your example above shows 1.0, but what's in the actual file?