# Send parameter from PHP to XSLT

Tags: php, xml, url, xslt

I'm trying to send an argument to my xsl but I can't succeed.. I don't understand why... I had a look to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218885/xsltprocessor-setparameter-send-an-undefined-number-of-params).

I don't think my XSL variable (nameArtist) has the value of my PHP variable ($_GET['name'], for example equals to Brodinski)

My files are :

PHP file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Zozor - Carnets de voyage</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

        // Load XML file
        $xml = new DOMDocument;
        $xml->load('artists.xml');

        // Load XSL file
        $xsl = new DOMDocument;
        $xsl->load('artist.xsl');

    $process = new XSLTProcessor;
    $process->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $process->setParameter('', 'nameArtist', $_GET['name'];);

    echo $process->transformToXML($xml);

?>
</body>
```

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="artist.rnc" type="application/relax-ng-compact-syntax"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="artist.xsl"?>

<ArtistCollection>
    <artist>
        <name>Brodinski</name>
        <musicCategory>Electronic</musicCategory>
        <originalCountry>Germany</originalCountry>
        <photo>esfsdfsf</photo>
    </artist>

    <artist>
        <name>Louis Armstrong</name>
        <musicCategory>Jazz</musicCategory>
        <originalCountry>United States</originalCountry>
    </artist>

    <artist>
        <name>Miles Davis</name>
        <musicCategory>Jazz</musicCategory>
        <originalCountry>United States</originalCountry>
    </artist>
</ArtistCollection>
```

XSLT File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="nameArtist" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Artists</h2>

                <p>salut <xsl:value-of select="$nameArtist" /></p>

                <xsl:for-each select="ArtistCollection/artist">

                    <table border="1">
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>category</th>
                            <th>country</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="musicCategory"/>  </td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="originalCountry"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm not a php developer, but the `;);` at the end of the line `$process->setParameter('', 'nameArtist', $_GET['name'];);` doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: Thank Simon, that is an error of copy/paste but was not the problem :).          It appears that the ligne "<xsl:param name="nameArtist" />" in the XSL file is the problem, without it, it works perfectly... But I don't really understand why

Comment: According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), _"The `<xsl:param>` element must be declared as a direct child of an `<xsl:template>` element"_. If you move it into the template, does that help?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie That is incorrect. To pass a parameter to the stylesheet at runtime, the parameter must be *global* (i.e. a child of  `<xsl:stylesheet>`): http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#top-level-variables

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Can you shed some light into why the OP's code works only when the `<xsl:param>` is removed from the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Old question with no accepted answer. The original code basically works here -> apache/php7.

I changed the semi colon, as previously mentioned, as well as the stylesheet declaration:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"  version="1.0">
```

as well as the set param, in the php:

```
$process->setParameter('', 'nameArtist', "this value")
```

I'd suggest the issue was either that, simply -> $_GET['name'] had no value, alternatively a server issue.